# iOS string localization command genstring fails

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

`genstring` command produces following error:

> find: MyViewController.m: unknown primary or operator

Full command:

```
$ find . -name *.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you calling genstrings? With the latest Xcode, you shouldn't have to do this at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If I have an old project, and now I want to add support for internationalization, then how should I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: Xcode 6 and above support exporting localizable content within .xliff files without you having to call ```ibtool``` or ```genstrings```. With your project open, select the project file, then click on Editor -> "Export for Localization..."

Comment: Ah! My knowledge of localization/internationalization is outdated. Thanks! While I have your attention, let me ask you this: Can you suggest a good free xliff editor? :)

Comment: Counterparts Lite (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/counterparts-lite/id711576477?mt=12) seems to be a popular choice.